# (How) can I generate coverage reports in PHP using XDebug?

Tags: php, testing, cypress, code-coverage, e2e

I use Cypress for E2E testing. Now I wonder, how can I produce coverage reports with PHP XDebug without PHPUnit? PCOV seams like a candidate; but this would again require to deactivate XDebug.

Tried XDebug, but it requires your tests to be written in PHPUnit.